# Sandbox NSOpenPanel Error 1000

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, sandbox, nsopenpanel

I'm pretty much ready to release the first sandbox-enabled Mac application.  The only entitlement that I need is **User Selected File**.  The user clicks on a toolbar button to select one or more image files, which doesn't cause trouble.  The user also clicks on a button to select a folder.  When they do, the Xcode output window indicates the following error message.  **CGSSetIgnoresCycle: error 1000 setting or clearing window tags**.  If the user cancels the select-folder operation without selecting one, they get an additional error message on top of the first one.  It says **PSsetwindowlevel, error setting window level (1000)**.  The application does not crash.  Are these error messages things that I need to worry?  If I ask Google, I don't get many search results.  Anyway, the following code is used when the user clicks on a button to select a folder.

```
- (IBAction)system1Selected:(id)sender {
    NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [panel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
    NSString *currentpath = systempath1.stringValue;
    if ([self fileExists:currentpath]) {
        [panel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:currentpath]];
    } else {
        [panel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self filePathA]]];
    }
    if ([panel runModal] != NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        //return nil;
    } else {
        NSURL *url = [[panel URLs] lastObject];
        systempath1.stringValue = [url path];
    }
}
```

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If I use 'try catch error,' I will have no more error messages.  But I wonder if I should go about finding the source of the errors.

Comment: 'fileExists' is a function that will return a boolean value for finding out whether the specified file or folder exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has been there for a while in all my applications. It doesn't seem something you need to worry about. It disappears without changing anything and, probably, it depends on a bug of the NSOpenPanel (I didn't manage to get the same error using the NSSavePanel).

In my opinion, there's no need to investigate further.

Comment: I see.  Thanks a lot for confirmation.